# Add the count of records in CosmosDB to an already existing SQL query that returns an existing set of results in one query

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to add the count as a property to the results being returned by the existing SQL query? or is getting the count separately the only way?

Query:

```
select * from c where 1=1 ORDER BY c.packageId OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10
```

(The query is built by 2 different strings, thats why there is 1=1)

Results:

```
[
    [
        {
            "a": [
                {
                    "ab": ""
                }
            ],
            "b": "a",
            "c": 0,
            "d": "0"
        },
        {
            "a": [
                {
                    "ab": ""
                }
            ],
            "b": "a",
            "c": 0,
            "d": "0"
        }
    ],
    null
]
```

What I would like, is to have the count of all records returned as a property in the results JSON, just how where you have the continuation token. This is an API, so I would like to include this information as part of the results instead of creating another API that only gets the count.

Comment: Please show an example of the query you're returning so we can see what you've done. Otherwise you can add count(*) as 'some_count' to any query.

Comment: made the changes

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to do this using sql.

As a workaround,you can do this by using [.Net SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-dotnet-standard).
Here is code:

```
    string sqlQueryText = "select * from c where 1=1 ORDER BY c.packageId OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10";
            
    QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);
    FeedIterator<Employee> feedIterator = this.container.GetItemQueryIterator<Employee>(queryDefinition);
    FeedResponse<Employee> response = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("ContinuationToken:" + response.ContinuationToken);
    Console.WriteLine("Count:" + response.Count);
```

Comment: I am using a framework that I am sharing with other APIs, so I would not like to change the way we implement the sdk.